# Why can I not get data from an associated table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations, relationship, models

In my Ruby on Rails application I am trying to display the first_name and last_name of the user who made a booking.

On the bookings/index.html.erb I have this:

```
<% @bookings.each do |booking| %>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><%= booking.user.first_name %> <%#= booking.user.last_name %></td>
                                        <td><%= booking.showing.film.title %></td>
                                        <td><%= booking.showing.show_date %></td>
                                        <td><%= booking.showing.show_time.strftime("%H:%M") %></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td><%= booking.seat.row_letter %><%= booking.seat.number %></td>
                                        <td style="padding-right:65px">
                                            <%#= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(user) %>  
                                            <%#= link_to 'Show', user_path(user) %>  
                                            <%#= link_to 'Destroy', user_path(user), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                <% end %>
```

The `booking.showing.film.title` and the code below that works but with the `booking.user.first_name` I get the error:

```
NoMethodError in Bookings#index     
undefined method `first_name' for nil:NilClass
```

But my models I think are set up correctly, user.rb:

```
has_many :bookings
```

bookings.rb:

```
belongs_to :user
```

bookings_controller:

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_booking, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /bookings
  # GET /bookings.json
  def index
    @bookings = Booking.all
  end

  # GET /bookings/1
  # GET /bookings/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /bookings/new
  def new
    @booking = Booking.new
  end

  # GET /bookings/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /bookings
  # POST /bookings.json
  def create
    @booking = Booking.new(booking_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @booking.save
        format.html { redirect_to @booking, notice: 'Booking was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @booking }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @booking.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /bookings/1
  # PATCH/PUT /bookings/1.json
  def update
     respond_to do |format|
      if @booking.update(booking_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @booking, notice: 'Booking was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @booking }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @booking.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /bookings/1
  # DELETE /bookings/1.json
  def destroy
     @booking.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to bookings_url, notice: 'Booking was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_booking
      @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
    end

   # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def booking_params
      params.require(:booking).permit(:showing_id, :user_id, :seat_id)
    end
end
```

Am I missing something? The attribute names and table names are correct.

Comment: Do you have user_id in your booking table?

Comment: You have some ``Booking`` in your ``@bookings`` collection that has an empty ``user``. There are different ways of dealing with that, first tell us if that is that is possible or show us more code (controller code for example)

Comment: What is the response of Booking.last.user in your rails console?

Comment: Yes, I've just checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using more than one dot is a violation of `Law of Demeter` and is considered as a **bad** practice. To follow the Law of Demeter, you can `delegate` the name to the `user` model and create a instance method in the `user` class to return the full name,

booking class

```
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  delegate :full_name, to: :user, prefix: true, allow_nil: true
end
```

user class

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bookings

  def full_name
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end
end
```

the view

```
<td><%= booking.user_full_name %></td>
```

If the user is `nil` this function will return gracefully return nil without complaining about not having a user.

It's always better to delegate the method calls ( don't mean `delegate` as a  keyword specifically ) rather than call wit so many dots, take `booking.showing.film.title` for example, there's so many things that could go wrong with this, if booking or showing or film changed any attribute you'll need to keep iterating on all your views and fix every one of them every time, instead try to create a centralized function called for example `booking.film_title`, then you only need to maintain it in a single place.

Answer (score 0):

because the `user` is nil so `booking.user` throws the error

Simply try this `booking.try(:user).try(:first_name)`

```
 <% @bookings.each do |booking| %>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><%= booking.try(:user).try(:first_name) %> <%= booking.try(:user).try(:last_name) %></td>
                                        <td><%= booking.showing.film.title %></td>
                                        <td><%= booking.showing.show_date %></td>
                                        <td><%= booking.showing.show_time.strftime("%H:%M") %></td>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td><%= booking.seat.row_letter %><%= booking.seat.number %></td>
                                        <td style="padding-right:65px">
                                            <%#= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(user) %>  
                                            <%#= link_to 'Show', user_path(user) %>  
                                            <%#= link_to 'Destroy', user_path(user), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                <% end %>
```

For more information of nil handling of click [try](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try)

Comment: That still doesn't work, and the user is not null, it has saved the user_id in the bookings table

Comment: did you use `booking.try(:user).try(:first_name)` and `booking.try(:user).try(:last_name)`

Comment: Please post your `index` method

Comment: I've uploaded the bookings_controller

Comment: `booking.try(:user).try(:first_name)` after using it can you please post your logs to show what exact error do you get ?

Answer (score 0):

You have correct set up associations.
But question is have you add `user_id` in your `booking` record, when you created it.

```
<% @bookings.each do |booking| %>
  <tr>
     <td><%= booking.user.try(:first_name) %> <%#= booking.user.try(:last_name) %></td>
     <td><%= booking.showing.film.title %></td>
     <td><%= booking.showing.show_date %></td>
     <td><%= booking.showing.show_time.strftime("%H:%M") %></td>
     <td></td>
     <td><%= booking.seat.row_letter %><%= booking.seat.number %></td>
     <td style="padding-right:65px">
       <%#= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(user) %>  
       <%#= link_to 'Show', user_path(user) %>  
       <%#= link_to 'Destroy', user_path(user), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
     </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

using method `try` will ensure that error does not occur

```
booking.user.try(:first_name) # display user first name if exist
booking.user.try(:last_name)  # display user last  name if exist
```

Open `rails c` and check which your `booking` record does not have `user_id`

Comment: That still does not work, the user_id in bookings is not blank. I tested this using the code: `<% if not booking.user_id.blank? %><%= booking.user.first_name %><% end %>`, but I still get the error, hence the booking has a user_id

Comment: I think you got error in the controller action `index` please post it

Comment: Even if the user_id is not blank, you can still get an error if there isn't a matching user